# replacing blank with zero sparksql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have created a query that returns users who placed order in a specific month and after how many months they have returned. the problem is when there's no user placed any order in a month it returns blank . I want to return zero instead .

I created a case statement as :

```
 case when user_id is null then 0 else user_id end
```

I also tried:

```
case when user_id is null and delivery_month is  null and returned_month is null then 0 else user_id end
```

if there's no row evaluated for the user, how can i replace that with 0 ?

this is how blank values looks like when I loaded data in the visualization tool:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share a sample of the raw data?

Comment: what is your schema ? if there is a blank, it is probably string.

Comment: [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce)